# Building Emulator from Sources

Tags: botframework

There are one or two recent fixes to the Bot Framework Emulator that I want to try but I can't see any nightly builds or any instructions on how to build from the source repo.  Any suggestions welcome.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is RTFM, see the CONTRIBUTING document...

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#how-to-build-from-source